# How to send data from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android Studio and Java, and I cannot resolve this problem I encountered. App keeps crashing whenever I try to send data from Activity to Fragment (tabOne) with Bundle, without that it's working just fine, but I need to send this "BeerDescription".

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NameClickListener{

List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> desc = new ArrayList<>();

private RecyclerView recycler;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupRecycler();
    setupRecyclerData();
}

private void setupRecycler(){
    recycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupRecyclerData(){
    titles.add("India Pale Ale");
    titles.add("Weissbier");
    titles.add("Lager");
    titles.add("Pale Ale");
    titles.add("Session Ipa");
    titles.add("Hoppy Lager");

    desc.add("Is a hoppy beer style within the broader category of pale ale. " +
            "The pale ales of the early eighteenth century were lightly hopped and quite different from today's pale ales." +
            "By the mid-eighteenth century, pale ale was mostly brewed with coke-fired malt, which produced less smoking and roasting of barley in the malting process, " +
            "and hence produced a paler beer.");
    desc.add("Usually top-fermented, which is brewed with a large proportion of wheat relative to the amount of malted barley. The two main varieties are Weißbier, based on " +
            "the German tradition, and Witbier, based on the Belgian tradition; other types include Lambic (made with wild yeasts and bacteria), Berliner Weisse (a cloudy, sour beer), " +
            "and Gose (a German-type sour, salty, herbal beer). ");
    desc.add("Lager is a type of beer conditioned at low temperatures.[1] Lagers can be pale, amber, or dark. Pale lager is the most widely consumed and commercially available style of beer. " +
            "Well-known brands include Pilsner Urquell, Molson Canadian, Miller, Stella Artois, Beck's, Brahma, Budweiser Budvar, Corona, Snow, Tsingtao, Singha, Kirin, Quilmes, Heineken, Kingfisher, " +
            "Carlsberg, Birra Moretti and Tennents. ");
    desc.add("Pale ale is a top-fermented beer made with predominantly pale malt.[1]"+
            "The highest proportion of pale malts results in a lighter colour.[2][3] The term first appeared around 1703 for beers made from malts dried with high-carbon coke, which resulted in a lighter " +
            "colour than other beers popular at that time. Different brewing practices and hop levels have resulted in a range of different tastes and strengths within the pale ale family.");
    desc.add("It’s not a Full Fat IPA, nor is it a Pale Ale, nor a British-styled sessionable pale beer, instead it fills in the middle of a hoppy Venn diagram of those three beer types. Reduce " +
            "the strength in an IPA, lose some of the maltier middle of a Pale Ale, load up the hops on a golden ale, dry it all out and give it a pokier bitterness and you’re in the Session IPA zone. " +
            "Given their rate of growth and their now-ubiquitous presence in bars and bottles shops, we’re all in the Session IPA zone.");
    desc.add("Clean personality of a lager with the hoppiness of an IPA.The basic idea behind a hoppy lager is pretty simple: a beer that mixes the best of a lager with the hoppy-quality often associated with " +
            "something like an IPA. This creates a beer that is light, refreshing, and easy to drink like a lager, which makes it perfect for Texas, with a more distinctive and complex flavor thanks to a stronger " +
            "hops presence. We find that our hoppy lager is easy to drink with a level of bitterness that is strong for a lager, but not quite as robust as an IPA.A good hoppy lager presents a middle way between a " +
            "traditional lager and something with more bitterness to it. It drinks a little like each, but ultimately has a personality all its own.");

    adapter.addData(titles, desc);
}

public void onNameClick(int position){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

    intent.putExtra("Title", titles.get(position));
    intent.putExtra("Description", desc.get(position));

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**NameViewHolder**

```
public class NameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

private ImageView ivCardImage;
private TextView tvCardTitle;
private TextView tvCardDescription;
private NameClickListener clickListener;

public NameViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, NameClickListener listener) {
    super(itemView);
    ivCardImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_cardImage);
    tvCardTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_CardTitle);
    tvCardDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_CardDescription);

    this.clickListener = listener;
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    tvCardTitle.setText(title);
}

public void setDescription(String description){
    tvCardDescription.setText(description);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    clickListener.onNameClick(getAdapterPosition());
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NameViewHolder> {

private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> descriptionList = new ArrayList<>();
private NameClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerAdapter(NameClickListener listener){
    this.clickListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View cellView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    return new NameViewHolder(cellView, clickListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NameViewHolder nameViewHolder, int position) {
    nameViewHolder.setTitle(titleList.get(position));
    nameViewHolder.setDescription(descriptionList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return titleList.size();
}

public String fetchTitle(int position){
    return this.titleList.get(position);
}

public String fetchDescription(int position){
    return this.descriptionList.get(position);
}

public void addData(List<String> titles, List<String> descriptions){
    this.titleList.clear();
    this.descriptionList.clear();

    this.titleList.addAll(titles);
    this.descriptionList.addAll(descriptions);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Main2Activity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

private String BeerName;
private String BeerDescription;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewpager;
private TabItem tabOne, tabTwo;
public PageAdapter pagerAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    BeerName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
    BeerDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("Description");
    setTitle(BeerName);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    tabOne tabone = new tabOne();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabOne = findViewById(R.id.tab_Description);
    tabTwo = findViewById(R.id.tab_Interesting);
    viewpager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewpager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Description", BeerDescription);
    tabone.setArguments(bundle);

    transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1, tabone);
    transaction.commit();

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else if(tab.getPosition() == 1){
                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
    viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
}
public String getBeerDescription(){
    return this.BeerDescription;
}
```

**TabOne fragment**

```
public class tabOne extends Fragment {
TextView tv_FragmentDescription;
String beerDesc;

public tabOne() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_one, container, false);
    tv_FragmentDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_tabOne_Description);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    beerDesc = bundle.getString("Description");
    tv_FragmentDescription.setText(beerDesc);

    return view;
}
```

**TabTwo fragment**

```
public class tabTwo extends Fragment {

public tabTwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_two, container, false);
}
```

**PageAdapter**

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private int numberOfTabs;

public PageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int numberoftabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numberOfTabs = numberoftabs;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new tabOne();
        default:
            return new tabTwo();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberOfTabs;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

**NameClickListener**

```
public interface NameClickListener {

void onNameClick(int position);
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is the error message? check it in your logcat!

Comment: can you post the error message that you are getting when you get the crash?

Comment: Process: beermap, PID: 5139
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{beermap/beermap.Main2Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08006e (beermap:id/frameLayout1) 
 for fragment tabOne{28fd673 (5a681e54-75b5-42d0-b4b7-3b0d709e5acd) id=0x7f08006e}
@MateoHervas

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08006e (beermap:id/frameLayout1) for fragment tabOne{28fd673 (5a681e54-75b5-42d0-b4b7-3b0d709e5acd) id=0x7f08006e}
@mangkool